# Android vision api OCR example is not detecting all text

Tags: android, android-vision

I have used picture which has text in black colour and white background

**Vision API is unable to read the text in that image, it reads first two line but rest all its not reading.**

Please let me know whats wrong. Is it problem with Api or from my code.

I used this  [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/ocr-reader)

Answer (score 1):

Text Vision api works by fetching different frames ,so when it recieves a suitable frame where it can recognize , it shows all the texts